# Create new Task or Thread each the time and close when it done

Tags: c#

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            ....
            timer.Interval = 5000; //number in milisecinds  
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            getData(); // Get data and store into DB
            WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
        }
```

I try create a services to check and get data from the Email.

My code above is mean each 5 seconds will recall `getData();`. My function `getData()` for get data and store into SQL Server. But sometimes, my `getData();` need 7-8 seconds to finish so if `timer.Interval = 5 seconds`   maybe fails.

My idea is create new `Thread` or `Task` for call `getData()` each 5 seconds and auto close when it finish. How can I do that?

Or please give some better idea or key words.

Comment: I don't understand what the desired behavior shall be here. Do you want: a) 5 sec. pause - start run 1 .3sec. end run 1 - 5 sec pause - start run 2 .7sec. end run 2 - 5 sec pause ... or b) 5sec. pause - start run 1 - after 5 sec. from start: discard start of run 2 - after 7sec. from start: end run 1 - 3 sec. pause - start run 2 or c) something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the work on a Task with Task.Run():

```
    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => getData());
    }
```

There could be some thread-safety issues though, depending on how `getData()` handles the data it uses. More about tasks can be found at [Task Class at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8)